# The meaning of " intellectual desert"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning, phrases

I have seen the phrase "intellectual desert" in the Cambridge Dictionary but I still don't understand its meaning. Can you explain what this phrase means?

Comment: It’s a figurative. “Desert” means like empty space. cultural, intellectual, etc. desert disapproving
 
a place that is considered to have no cultural, intellectual, etc. quality or interest: